# Algebraic Geometry - Confusion about a line of a lecture note

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading algebraic geometry lecture notes written by Andreas Gathmann. In chapter $2$ Proposition $2.8$ he wrote that:

"Proposition $2.8.$ A non-empty affine variety X is irreducible if and only if $A(X)$ is not an integral domain.

*Proof.* As $X$ is non-empty, its coordinate ring $A(X)$ is not the zero ring (which by definition is not an integral domain).

..."

I failed to understand what "by definition is not an integral domain" means here. Does it mean that if $X$ is a non-empty affine variety, $A(X)$ is not an integral domain? Is this even true?

I might have misunderstood what Gathmann means. Here's a link to this specific chapter. Thanks!

[https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c2.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c2.pdf)

Comment: You've added a "not," but I don't know if fixing it addresses your confusion.  "A non-empty affine variety X is irreducible if and only if A(X) is an integral domain."

Comment: The zero ring is not an integral domain, by definition.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Thank you!